# Why doesn't help(module) work in python interpreter?

Tags: python

Why do I get an exception on the last one (python 3.9.2)?

```py
>>> import os
>>> help(type(os))  # => Help on class module in module builtins
>>> help(int)       # => Help on class int in module builtins
>>> help(module)    # => NameError: name 'module' is not defined
```

Shouldn't it be equivalent to the second line since `module` is in builtins?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman That's what I assumed from the message provided by `help(type(os))`.

Comment: What did you expect to get as output from `help(module)`? If you're looking for the module class, try `help(types.ModuleType)`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I was assuming that for any `x` in `builtins` I could get help for `x` with `help(x)` but that was obviously wrong. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: No, that's not wrong at all. It's just that `module` isn't a thing that exists in `builtins`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no symbol named `module` by default, so you can't ask the help function to describe it. The description is that it is *from the module* `builtins`, not that there's a symbol named `module`.

You can ask for help about `builtins`, as long as you make sure to import the symbol / module first:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> help(builtins)
```

If you're looking for something representing the actual, internal `module` class, you can use `types.ModuleType`:

```
>>> from types import ModuleType
>>> ModuleType
<class 'module'>
>>> help(ModuleType)
Help on class module in module builtins:

class module(object)
 |  module(name, doc=None)
 |
 |  Create a module object.
 |
 |  The name must be a string; the optional doc argument can have any type.
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
...
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly there is a class `module` defined in package `builtins` but that symbol is not exported by this package.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct; but you can get a reference to this module through `types.ModuleType` and call help on that class.